# Java exception error when building android in ionic framework

Tags: java, ionic-framework

I am trying to set up an ionic environment to start working on my projects. but every time I try to build an ionic app it always stopped.

I use this:

```
ionic build android
```

and I get this error:

```
  ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build /home/AAA/myApp
    ionic-app-scripts build

    [18:22:15]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45 
    [18:22:15]  build prod started ... 
    [18:22:15]  clean started ... 
    [18:22:15]  clean finished in 7 ms 
    [18:22:15]  copy started ... 
    [18:22:15]  ngc started ... 
    [18:22:15]  copy finished in 83 ms 
    [18:22:33]  ngc finished in 18.74 s 
    [18:22:33]  webpack started ... 
    [18:22:44]  webpack finished in 10.72 s 
    [18:22:44]  uglifyjs started ... 
    [18:22:44]  sass started ... 
    [18:22:46]  sass finished in 2.20 s 
    [18:22:46]  cleancss started ... 
    [18:22:48]  cleancss finished in 1.67 s 
    [18:22:59]  uglifyjs finished in 15.23 s 
    [18:22:59]  build prod finished in 44.73 s 
    ANDROID_HOME=/home/AAA/.Android/Sdk

    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

    Subproject Path: CordovaLib

    Deleting directory /home/AAA/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh/gradle-2.14.1


    Unzipping /home/AAA/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to /home/AAA/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh

    Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
            at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.copyInputStream(Install.java:189)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:175)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
            ... 3 more

    Error: /home/AAA/myApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
            at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
            at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.copyInputStream(Install.java:189)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:175)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
            ... 3 more
```

I am using nodjs 6.9.1 running on linux mint 18 ( ubuntu 16.04 ) x64

Comment: Looks like a corrupt zip/jar file

Comment: @MadPhysicist the file "gradle-2.14.1-all.zip" is fine but inside it, there are about 49 jar files. even though if I run the command again it will delete the folder and start over causing the same problem.

Comment: Get a new copy of the file. Zips are written sequentially to the best of my knowledge, so it is possible that only one (or a few) of the inner files became corrupt. Also, do a hash-check (probably MD5 or SHA1) when you download the file next time. This sort of thing is exactly what hashes are provided for.

Comment: While it is possible that someone has run into this exact issue before, I think that it is very unlikely that it will be reproduced exactly, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, delete any apk output before retrying, worked for me.